# How to fetch the un-ordered product from the product table in laravel with pagination?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables 
Product Table : Columns( id , product_name,product_image,price)
Order Table : Columns(id,Product_id,user_id,ordered_on)

I have a listing page (Initially i list all the products from the product table)
If the product is added to the cart then it has to be removed from the cart based on the user .

I have written the query like this :

```
 $menuspecial=Product::paginate(10)->toArray();
 foreach($menuspecial as $menu){
        $menuinfo = Cart::where('product_id',$menu['id'])->where('user_id',$id)->first();
        if(!isset($menuinfo)){
            $menuvalue[] = $menu->get();
        }
```

During api response i'm not getting the pagination data(such as next url, page..ect)

Thanks in advance .

Comment: have you tried `simplePaginate(10)` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: @chasenyc if we returns using the foreach data then the pagination data wont be shown right , if there is any other way to fetch the data from both the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove the cart items from appearing again in the products menu. Do this.

```
    $cartProducts = Cart::where('user_id',$id)
        ->get()
        ->pluck('product_id')
        ->toArray();

    $productMenu = Product::whereNotIn('id', $cartProducts)
        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: what will be the next page url , how it takes it.

Comment: You can read more about pagination in the official doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination, it generates the next page url using the page get input which is set to 'page' by default and next page number calculated based on the remaining result set.